# File Downloaded Using Python Requests Module Throwing Invalid File Error

Tags: python, python-requests

I have the following code that downloads zip files from a URL.  I have used the requests module of Python.

For the URL = "https://www1.nseindia.com/content/historical/DERIVATIVES/2018/OCT/fo23OCT2018bhav.csv.zip", the code returns a zip file of 557KB.

However, for URL = "https://www1.nseindia.com/content/historical/DERIVATIVES/2015/OCT/fo23OCT2015bhav.csv.zip", the code returns a zip file of 1KB.  Upon trying to open this 1KB file, it throws an error "Windows Cannot Open the Folder.  The Compressed (Zipped) Folder is invalid."

Apparently, when I try to download the file using a browser for URL = "https://www1.nseindia.com/content/historical/DERIVATIVES/2015/OCT/fo23OCT2015bhav.csv.zip"), it downloads a file of 341KB.

What is working using a browser is not working using the python code.

Here is the URL through which one can navigate and download the data:

https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/archieve_fo.htm
One has the select Report = Bhavcopy and Date as 23-10-2015

Am I missing something in the code?

Appreciate your help in this.

thanks,

```
import os
import time
import datetime
import requests
from zipfile import ZipFile
from random import choice

desktop_agents = ['Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.80 Safari/537.36 Edg/86.0.622.48']

def random_headers():
    return {'User-Agent': choice(desktop_agents),'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'}

today = datetime.date(2015,10,23)
#today = datetime.date(2018,10,23)

date=today.strftime('%d')
month=today.strftime('%b').upper()
year=today.strftime('%Y')

url="https://www1.nseindia.com/content/historical/DERIVATIVES/2015/OCT/fo23OCT2015bhav.csv.zip"
#url="https://www1.nseindia.com/content/historical/DERIVATIVES/2018/OCT/fo23OCT2018bhav.csv.zip"

#url = "https://www1.nseindia.com/content/historical/DERIVATIVES/" + year + "/" + month + "/" + "fo" + date + month + year + "bhav.csv.zip"
folder = "C:\\Temporary\\"
filename1 = folder + "fo" + date + month + year + "bhav.csv.zip"

print(url)

req = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True, headers=random_headers())
file= open(filename1,'wb').write(req.content)
```

[Image of Website Through Manual Navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBjUb.png)

Comment: When I click on the link https://www1.nseindia.com/content/historical/DERIVATIVES/2015/OCT/fo23OCT2015bhav.csv.zip I get access denied. Is that correct?

Comment: When I click on the link, it downloads a 341KB zip file.  Can a link and access to it behave differently for different users?

Comment: @lenmet yes the behavious will change under various circumstances,
using your browsers cookies in request session may help

Comment: Is the behavior anything to do with the region from where it is accessed or for that matter, the user agent.  Can you try the other URL for 2018?  Does that too give you access denied error?  I specified the user agent in the code to avoid "access denied" or other issues.

Comment: I have included the URL through which one can manually navigate and download the date for 2015-10-23, and it works.  What is the reason for it to not work through the code?